# Fifo/shift register starting value duplicated

Tags: verilog

Can someone tell me why  i got a duplicated start value in simulation for this implementation of shift register in verilog code :

```
module fifo(
  input clk,rst,
  input[7:0] data_in,
  output[7:0] data_out
);
  reg[23:0] fifo =0;
  always @(posedge clk)
    begin
      fifo <= {fifo[15:0],data_in};
    end
  assign data_out = fifo;
endmodule
```

How can I remove this duplication ?
[image]

Comment: Do you have testbench Verilog code?  If so, post that also so we can see how you drive the `fifo` inputs.

Comment: i am just using GUI command "force constant" on "data_in" as you can see on the picture. No testbench ,since i have just started learning. I am using vivado from xilinx.

Comment: I don't use vivado.  How are you controlling the delays between data_in values?  Can you edit your question to show that?  Do you do it in the gui?  Maybe post a screen shot.

Comment: yes, basically you define the clock period of `clk` in GUI, and you use the step command with the same amount (10ns for `clk` period and step every 10ns and with every step i change `data_in` from time 0). For me, it's a problem with the tool Vivado, since the code is pretty simple and i found similar code on the web.

Comment: I am going to update later my question with a testbench, in case, it does not change anything.

Comment: It is trivial to create a testbench that will work.  But, that won't answer your question about why vivado gives you unexpected results or how to fix it in vivado.  The key is to drive the inputs synchronous with the clock in a way the the verilog simulator considers synchronous.

Comment: Best guess is data_in is being updated before the first clock. Make sure the clock is updated first.

Comment: @Greg I tried your idea. but vivado does not make a difference. thank you  i did it with a testbench

Comment: @toolic Well the testbench worked perfectly, 
I don't know the way the verilog simulator in vivado works but since Vivado gives me a lot a trouble until now that makes me feel unproductive, i am not going to dig further the problem. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the input data at the same instant that the clock is rising. That causes unpredictable behavior in simulation and in real life.

You must respect the setup and hold time requirements for your register. In simulation you often can get buy with just 1 ns between any change in the data and the rising edge of the clock.

Comment: I added a 1ns delay for `clk` and it worked as expected. The testbench I tried also worked without any delay. 
I thought that in behavioral simulation setup/hold time does not matter (a perfect world), otherwise how can we explain later changes in `data_in` values `bb` `cc` made exactly at posedge of `clk` ? . In many runs, i got the same result so it's pretty deterministic (at least in simulation). 
do you take into account setup/hold time in your testbench ? anyway thank you for the response.

Comment: In a testbench you need to make sure that the input data never changes at the same time as a rising clock edge (assuming rising-edge flip-flops). In a testbench with ideal models **absolute** time does not matter but **relative** time does, and internal to the simulator we can't be sure whether the data input of a flip-flop or its clock input will actually be update first if the testbench changes them at the same time. It may be **deterministic** for a given simulation on a given simulator, and **sometimes** everything might work as expected, but in general the behavior is unpredictable.

Comment: Systemverilog has a feature called a 'clocking block' specifically designed to handle this and related timing issues that occur between the testbench and the device under test.  Search 'systemveriog clocking block', you will find many tutorials on the topic.  IMO its worth starting new testbenches with clocking blocks to avoid this debug.

Comment: @Mikef I looked into this quickly, and if understood, yes,  it takes control from simulators over the relationship between signals and clock. But for now I will stick with Verilog because  that what vivado use. 

ElliotAlderson So if you say it's a common practice to  diferentiate changing time of clock and signals explicitly, I will take it for my future testbenches. it's not  a hard to do it.

thank you again.